# Customize . well-known configurations in npm oidc-provider library

Tags: openid-connect, oidc-provider, node-oidc-provider

I am using npm package panva's oidc-provider to implement features of OIDC for login.

I want to override a few well known configurations of OIDC provider.

Well known configuration url:

`<EXTERNAL DNS OF AUTH SERVER>/.well-known/openid-configuration`

For example : I want to override the `<EXTERNAL DNS OF AUTH SERVER>/token` end point to `<INTERNAL DNS OF AUTH SERVER>/token`

Is any such feature given by the library?

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use middlewares. You control the complete response in the post-middleware, so change it to whatever you need, whenever you need.

https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/docs/README.md#pre--and-post-middlewares

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize the node-oidc-provider .well-known configuration url, the best way is:

- update default params as you need
- Use the **discovery** field of the configuration to add custom field

```js
/** Hold all the OIDC Provider configurations */
module.exports = {

    /** https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/tree/main/docs#discovery */
    discovery: discovery,

    /** @See https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/tree/main/docs#findaccount */
    findAccount: Account.findAccount,

    /** @See https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/tree/main/docs#clients  */
    clients: clients,

// Others configurations
}
```